# Create labels.csv file ground truth (gt.txt)

Tags: python

I have a `gt.txt` file and I would like to convert it into `labels.csv` file. There is a difference between the two of these files.

**gt.txt**

[image]

**labels.csv** (Require)

The labels.csv should contain two columns the first column name is `filename` and `words` is the second column name. **How I can do it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `pandas`, then you can try this

```
import pandas as pd

# Read space-separated columns without header
data = pd.read_csv('gt.txt', sep="\s+", header=None)

# Update columns
data.columns = ['filename', 'words']

# Save to required format
data.to_csv('labels.csv')
```

Comment: Please let me know one thing more, In my filename column most rows like this are "images/2/29682.jpg". I want to replace "images/2/" in all rows it start from 0 to 50 like images/0/2968332.jpg, images/1/2933682.jpg, images/2/2339682.jpg

Comment: Check out [pandas.DataFrame.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) and use it with regex.

Answer (score 1):

**gt.txt** file

```
0.jpg img1
1.jpg img2
2.jpg img3
3.jpg img4
4.jpg img5
5.jpg img6
```

Python Code to convert **.txt** to **.csv**

```
text_file = 'gt.txt' # enter path to gt.txt file
csv_file = 'labels.csv' # enter path to labels.csv file

with open(csv_file, 'w') as wrt_csv:
    with open(text_file, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            line = line.split(' ')
            line = ','.join(line)
            wrt_csv.write(line) # \n is already in the line so no need to add it
```

Paste the above code on **[any_name].py** file and run it using **python [any_name].py**

Above code will generate **label.csv**

```
0.jpg,img1
1.jpg,img2
2.jpg,img3
3.jpg,img4
4.jpg,img5
5.jpg,img6
```

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: Please let me know one thing more, In my filename column most rows like this are "images/2/29682.jpg". The middle integer "2", starts from 0 to 50 like images/0/2968332.jpg, images/1/2933682.jpg, images/2/2339682.jpg. I want to replace "images/2/" in all rows. How i can do?

Comment: You can use for loop in it..